# Как сделать автоматичиское возпрозвидение видео с ютуба?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Встраиваю видео плеер с ютуб к себе на сайт . Как сделать автоматичиское возпроизвидение  видео после загрузки страницы  ?

```html
   <iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SzjRWbGBLqQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметр [autoplay](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=ru#autoplay) поможет в этом.

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
        src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com" />
```

Если используется JS API (осторожно — deprecated o_0), для воспроизведения есть метод [playVideo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_controls).